# How can a containerized JAR (Java) access the default system mixer?

Tags: java, docker, audio, device, mixer

I previously took this question down, it's going back up since it's still a problem we're encountering. We have a JAR that we're resurrecting from three years ago. Back then (before I joined the project), it ran bare-metal (presumably on an RPM-based Linux distribution). Before a developer left, he had containerized it (CentOS7) and left us with very little documentation.

Ultimately, the JAR is calling the function getSourceDataLine() described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getSourceDataLine(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat)

> The returned line will be provided by the default system mixer, or, if not possible, by any other mixer installed in the system that supports a matching SourceDataLine object.

However, the program encounters an IllegalArgumentException

> if the system does not support at least one source data line supporting the specified audio format through any installed mixer

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian is supported.  
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:479)  
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(AudioSystem.java:606)
```

I inspected the contents of the sound.properties file: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/sound.properties` inside the container and `./jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.322.b06-2.el8_5.x86_64/jre/lib/sound.properties` on the host. Both are completely commented/empty, so I assume the default system mixer is being used.

In the docker/docker-compose run parameters, I tried adding all capabilities to the Linux container, and that did not resolve the issue (regardless of permissions, I assume the needed sound card device doesn't appear at all).

I suspected there was a `--device` flag that could be passed to the `docker run` command (or docker-compose yaml). However, I tried running the container as privileged (access to all host devices), and this did not allow access to a system mixer.

I may try inspecting the devices available to the Java runtime with code similar to here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4269230

I have heard "audio is difficult in containers". I may try doing full virtualization with QEMU to to try to recreate the host environment, but that seems a little drastic. If anyone has worked with the Java audio system as well as containers and could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just debug the Heck out of it. I once worked almost entirely for a day on Qemu and it seems implausible to fathom. Plus you are adding a lot of junk around it - and those peaches better arrive proper and crisp cause otherwise I'm not paying a dime. and  of course whatever you put in quotes is the true saying so you better believe it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux accessing the audio devices is all done via the filesystem. So if you mount the necessary files (/dev/audio?) into the container and give suitable privileges you should be good to go.

Comment: This is the closest to what got us past our error. We passed a "privileged" to the container to access all devices, but the device itself had no sound card. We moved the container to one with /dev/snd and that let us reach the next error. Know your hardware!

Comment: Congratulations!